# Basic LEFT JOIN in MySQL is very slow

Tags: sql, mysql

This seems like a simple SQL query, but it takes 2.9 seconds. And this is just a tiny version of what I need to actually run, so the final product takes far too long to process.

I have two tables, the main one:

main_collection

```
+------------+
| main_index |
+------------+
|      37987 |
|       6967 |
|       4424 |
|      12647 |
|      11771 |
|       2569 |
|       7352 |
|       7156 |
|      13760 |
|       6666 |
+------------+
```

And the one I want to LEFT JOIN:

mc_revs_language_id

```
+-----------+-------+
| row_index | value |
+-----------+-------+
|     11771 |     1 |
|      7352 |     1 |
|     50605 |    61 |
|     50605 |    63 |
|     50605 |    61 |
|     11771 |    62 |
|     50605 |    16 |
|         3 |    16 |
|         3 |     2 |
|         3 |     2 |
+-----------+-------+
```

Except both tables are much larger than this. ~2000 for main_collection and ~12,000 for mc_revs_language_id. Both have a PRIMARY KEY.

The query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(`main_collection`.`main_index`) AS `cnt`
FROM `main_collection`
LEFT JOIN `mc_revs_language_id` ON mc_revs_language_id.row_index = main_collection.main_index
```

With EXPLAIN:

```
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table               | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                           |
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | main_collection     | index | NULL          | id   | 326     | NULL | 10776 | Using index                                     |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | mc_revs_language_id | ALL   | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  2182 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I have no idea what to take from the EXPLAIN. Does anyone know why this is taking so long? If I change LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN it returns the result in 0.005 seconds.

Edit: SHOW CREATE TABLE main_collection:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `main_collection` (
  `main_index` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(130) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `publish_time` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `channel` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `native_only` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `hidden` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`main_index`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`,`service`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=60288 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE mc_revs_language_id:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `mc_revs_language_id` (
  `index` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `row_index` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mw_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`index`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43763 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

I also put the SQL here: https://dbfiddle.uk/K1Z_GdLA.

Edit: I found a faster query I could use, but I'll leave this up because I'm still curious in case anyone wants to answer.

Comment: Why is the main_collection index key length 326 bytes?  That seems large.

Comment: Please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table tablename` for both tables

Comment: What language are you using when applying the SQL? COUNT()-function is rather slow. If you could just use SELECT and then calculate result after getting the result back, it would probably be faster.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld that is almost never going to be true

Comment: @ysth - I agee that is in most cases this would not be the issue, but in this I believe it's worth a try :-)

Comment: @Dima - Forgive me for asking, but do you have more fields in the tables you are describing?

Comment: try `count(*)` instead of nominating an unindexed column in the count function, plus add indexes to both columns used in the join. see: https://dbfiddle.uk/7L3X04eY  you really need to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to solicit a more precise answer

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I'm not even sure what that number represents. The structure of the table has an Int(11) for the key.

Comment: If you'll be frequently using the row_index field for JOIN and / or QUERYING, then you probably have to define an INDEX on it @Dima

Comment: @ysth Added to post.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Yep, there are more fields.

Comment: @Paul I put the SQL here: https://dbfiddle.uk/K1Z_GdLA. I greatly decreased the number of rows, but the SQL is the same. Also, I don't know if my server just needed a rest, but now it's running the query instantaneously. I don't think I changed anything in the meantime.

Comment: @php-dev Oh, ok, I didn't know that was a thing. I thought I just needed one index on each table (that's what I have, right? with the PRIMARY KEY)

Comment: Can you add an index to the mc_revs_language_id table? This will make sure the join hits an index, which _should_ improve performance...
create index r on mc_revs_language_id (row_index);

Comment: @NevilleKuyt Adding an index makes this, and my much more complex query, work instantaneously, thanks!

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld "What language are you using when applying the SQL?" Just in the mariadb terminal. But the issue seems to be fixed with INDEXes.

Comment: FWIW the reason the inner join was much faster was it was able to read all of mc_revs_language_id and join main_collection quickly using its index; with a left join it isn't possible to reverse the tables

Comment: IMHO Why handle null values with kind of outer join ? New relational languages have deprecated either null and outer join concepts. You can get exactly the same result by using a Union between  table1 inner joined with table2 AND elements from table1 where those elements are not on table2

Comment: @Dima - I'm glad it worked out for you!